# Can I make emacsclient start alternate-editor in the background?

Tags: macos, emacs, emacsclient

I have installed Emacs 24 on my Mac using homebrew, and similar to another question (listed below), I would like to use the same command when first starting Emacs as I do when opening additional files from the command line. To this end, I have set up an alias (modified a bit for readability):

```
EAPP=/usr/local/Cellar/emacs/24.3/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS
alias emacs='emacsclient -a $EAPP/Emacs -n'
```

Here's the twist: I put the `-n` (same as `--no-wait`) at the end because I like not having to hit `C-x #` to finish buffers. A side effect that I like is that it returns immediately to the command line.

Could there be a way to alter my alias to make the first-time run go in the background as well?  Or should I just teach my fingers to put a `&` after every invocation of my `emacs` alias?

Question about making emacs and emacsclient seem the same:

- [Emacs - connect to daemon (if it exists) without using emacsclient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8328469/emacs-connect-to-daemon-if-it-exists-without-using-emacsclient)

Comment: I think most people use the daemon which can be launched without Emacs even being visible so there is no need to worry about an extra step to background it -- e.g., something like this:  https://gist.github.com/ambethia/304964

Comment: I am not sure I understood you question correctly so pardon me I misunderstood something. Doesn't the following do what you want?  `emacsclient -c -a='' -n <filename>`, this will check if server is running if not start it (`-a=''`), then start a new frame (`-c`) and returns immediately (`-n`).

Comment: @IqbalAnsari, when I tried the empty alternate editor (`-a=''`) emacsclient invoked the Apple-installed version of Emacs rather than the one I installed via homebrew. The alias I have above does mostly what I want, except that it doesn't go into the background the first time running.

Comment: @lawlist, running the daemon at login sounds like it will work well for me. I'll give it a try.

Comment: @amacleod the empty alternate editor starts the Apple-installed app because that is the emacs in the `PATH` variable, I remember facing this issue to resolve it add **prepend** `/usr/local/Cellar/emacs/24.3/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS` to your path.